# Retrieving data from Oracle UCM server

Tags: java, oracle-ucm

So this is the first time I'm doing this kind of task, so apologizes if something doesn't make sense at the beginning.
So essentially I have a UCM server from where I need to retrieve data.
I've with me a pdf provided by Oracle where they also stored some JAVA code to perform the action.

However, there's something I'm not understanding:
They mention I need to have the oracle.ucm.fa_client_11.1.1.jar.
I has to be included in the classpath and it contains the Java API for connecting to UCM Server.

First question is: where can I find it?
It seems it's related with Webcenter Content Document Transfer Utility java app, am I wrong?
The goal of my task is simply to retrieve files from UCM to my local machine, but I'm missing some dependencies.

Can someone help me?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: There are easier ways. Have a look at RIDC.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I ended up by choosing it and solved my life. Thank you! :)